# GSAP SVG Transform Origin bad behavior

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, gsap

I'm trying to make this orbits rotates from the center (transfrom-origin: 50% 50%) but why it's still moving?

```
  // Show Premium
  function showPremuimPackage(el) {

 // if Premium is selected
  if(planetAdvance.hasClass('unselected') && planetEssential.hasClass('unselected')) {
    let tlArrange = new TimelineMax();

    tlArrange
    // move selected
    .to(premiumOrbit, .6,{transformOrigin:"center", rotation: '-50%', ease:Power1.easeOut})
    .to(planetPremium, .6,{rotation: 50,transformOrigin:"50% 50%", scale: '2', ease:Power1.easeOut},'-=1')
    // move unselected
      // Advanced
      .to(advanceOrbit, .6,{rotation: "50%", transformOrigin:"center", ease:Power1.easeOut},'-=.5')
//           .to(planetAdvance, .6,{scale: '.4.5', rotation: -50, 
transformOrigin:"50% 50%", ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=.5')
//           // Essential
//           .to(essentialOrbit, .6,{rotation: '-50%', 
transformOrigin:"50% 50%", ease:Power1.easeOut},'-=.5')
//           .to(planetEssential, .6,{transformOrigin:"50% 50%", 
ease:Power1.easeOut},'-=.5')

    ;


  }
  }
```

https://codepen.io/G-ROS/pen/WOrMrb

Why its doesn't rotate in the middle. And if you keep clicking the other planets it get a mess (need to uncomment to see it ). What I need to do to keep things always centered and not move around when rotating. 
Thanks a lot guys.